# How to make the button No. 1 go back to the previous state after clicking the button No. 2?

Tags: javascript

I click `Change1` button - Test 1 row turns the background red. I click `Change2` button - Test 2 row changes the background to red, but Test 1 stays with a red background and I don't want that. When you click the Change button, only the row assigned to it should change the background color - the rest stays blue. How to do it ?
I want a similar form of code based on `getElementsByClassName` i `scrollIntoView`

https://jsfiddle.net/oyt9L7u4/2/

Comment: Do you change the other backgrounds to blue in your code?

Comment: Like this : `y[1].style.background = "red"; y[0].style.background = "blue"; y[2].style.background = "blue"; y[3].style.background = "blue"; y[4].style.background = "blue";` ?

Comment: The lines in that comment which set the colors to `"blue"` are missing in the code you linked to...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5b4a9spt/ is that correct ?

Comment: Have you tested it?  Does it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
function myFunction(index) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("testRow");
  [...x].forEach(el => el.style.background = "blue")
  x[index].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'center'
  });
 
  x[index].style.background = "red";
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr,
td {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

tr {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(0)">Change1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(1)">Change2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(2)">Change3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(3)">Change4</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(4)">Change5</button>
<table>
  <tr class="testRow">
    <td>Test1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="testRow">
    <td>Test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="testRow">
    <td>Test3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="testRow">
    <td>Test4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="testRow">
    <td>Test5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You. Is that possible to `scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'center'});` works in Safari/Edge ? I am using `<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/smoothscroll-polyfill@0.4.4/dist/smoothscroll.min.js"></script>` for `Smooth`, but it still scroll on top position.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the last changed element in an variable to change it back to red.
also you can use classes to apply or remove styles

CSS

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr,
td {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

tr {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.style{
  background : red;
}
```

JS

```
if(store!= undefined){
    store.classList.remove("style")
}

  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("testRow");
    store = x[num];
x[num].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'center'
  });
  x[num].classList.add("style")
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6407yufw/1/